# Livewire data binding issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to learn to use livewire. So I started with docs and screencasts. I was building a Laravel project using Jetstream with Livewire scaffolding.
The problem seems to be that the controller does not pass the variables to the blade template.

I previously made a test project, using just Laravel 8, modifying the `welcome.blade.php` template and requiring Livewire by composer. And it worked just fine.

Steps to Reproduce: Create a Laravel 8.x jetstream project and use my code

Here's my code:

In: App\Http\Livewire\AddPost.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class AddPost extends Component
{
    public $title = "Blank";
    public $content = "Such empty here";
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.add-post');
    }
}
```

In: resources/views/add-post.blade.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        @livewireStyles
    </head>

    <body>
        @livewire('add-post')

        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

In: resources\views\livewire\add-post.blade.php

```
<div>
    Title: {{ $title }}
    <br>
    Content: {{ $content }}
</div>
```

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/aleemont/PHPBookingSystem)

Comment: Not able to replicate this with the exact same code in the exact same folders. You must be doing something else that you're not showing here. Either you're hitting a different route/view than the outer one, or something else - because the code itself works.

Comment: What do you mean? I will publish a git hub repo so you can check everything, is this ok?

Comment: Your route is wrong. `Route::get('add-post', App\Http\Livewire\AddPost::class)->name('add-post');` to render the Livewire component directly, or you should return the outer view, `Route::get('add-post/', function () {
    return view('add-post');
})->name('add-post');`

Comment: Worked. thank you. I think I'll have to study routing better tho

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.add-post', [
        'title' => $this->title,
        'content' => $this->content
    });
}
```

OR

```
@livewire('add-post', ['title' => 'lorem ipsum', '' => 'content'])
```

OR use this function, it is like a constructor().

```
public function mount() {
    $this->title = 'lorem ipsum';
    $this->content = 'content';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in app.blade.php: {{$slot}}

```
 <html>
     <head>
         @livewireStyles
     </head>
 
     <body>
         {{ $slot }}                   <<<<<<<--------------
 
         @livewireScripts
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
public $title;
public $content;

public function mount(){
$this->title= "Blank";
$this->content= "Such empty here";
}
```