# Livewire: Data Binding not working from UI to controller to UI

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

When ever I tries to use live wire data binding
It give 404 error

contact-form.blade.php

```
<div wire.transition.fade key="unique-key">
    <input wire:model="named" class="w-full px-5 py-3 border border-gray-400 rounded-lg outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" />
    {{$named}}
</div>
```

Contactform.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class ContactForm extends Component
{
    public $named = "jelly";

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.contact-form', ['named' => $this->named])->layout('layouts.app');;
    }

    public function mount($named)
    {
        $this->named =$named;
    }
}
```

Error

[image]

its simple data binding from UI to controller in Html inspect wire id is same as wire id present in html request,

[Livewire data binding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935291/livewire-data-binding-issues) this solution also not worked for me
[image]

Comment: Since its a public property, you don't need `['named'=>$this->named]` in your `view()` method. And the `layouts.app` is the default, so it doesn't *have* to be specified either.

Comment: @Qirel NO DIFFERENCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall from Larvel >7 version to specified laravel 7 solve my issue